# Move Chat bubble to right

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to create a chat window from the reference 
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/open-in-chat-popup-box-chat-popup
(a big thanks to Gurdeep Osahan for making this open to everyone).
I am trying to build a communication between Client and Vendor.
I want the to be aligned on left, which is already there so no efforts on that, and vendor on the right, which is creating headache for me.I have no idea from where to start. I tried "pull-right", but everything messes up on that .I am completely new to UI design. Any help/suggestions to proceed will be very helpful. I have attached the link here.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nishantaujju/skp0cm4u/2/)

**Edit 1:**
I thing I couldn't explain my question correctly. 
I want the To and From inside the div to be on different side. [image: Example]

```js
  $(function(){
$("#addClass").click(function () {

          $('#qnimate').addClass('popup-box-on');
            });
          
            $("#removeClass").click(function () {
          $('#qnimate').removeClass('popup-box-on');
            });
  })
```

```css
   
.popup-box {
   background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
    height: 415px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 70px;
    width: 300px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.round.hollow {
    margin: 40px 0 0;
}
.round.hollow a {
    border: 2px solid #ff6701;
    border-radius: 35px;
    color: red;
    color: #ff6701;
    font-size: 23px;
    padding: 10px 21px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.round.hollow a:hover {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 35px;
    color: red;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 23px;
    padding: 10px 21px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.popup-box-on {
    display: block !important;
}
.popup-box .popup-head {
    background-color: #fff;
    clear: both;
    color: #7b7b7b;
    display: inline-table;
    font-size: 21px;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    width: 100%;
     font-family: Oswald;
}
.bg_none i {
    border: 1px solid #ff6701;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: #ff6701;
    font-size: 17px;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 33px;
}
.bg_none:hover i {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 17px;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 33px;
}
.bg_none {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: medium none;
}
.popup-box .popup-head .popup-head-right {
    margin: 11px 7px 0;
}
.popup-box .popup-messages {
}
.popup-head-left img {
    /*border: 1px solid #7b7b7b;*/
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 44px;
}
.popup-messages-footer > textarea {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b2b2b2 !important;
    height: 40px !important;
    margin: 7px;
    padding: 5px !important;
     border: medium none;
    width: 95% !important;
}
.popup-messages-footer {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.popup-messages-footer .btn-footer {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2px 5px 10px 6px;
    width: 100%;
}
.simple_round {
    background: #d1d1d1 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #4b4b4b !important;
    height: 21px;
    padding: 0 0 0 1px;
    width: 21px;
}





.popup-box .popup-messages {
    background: #3f9684 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 275px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.direct-chat-messages {
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    
}
.popup-messages .chat-box-single-line {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a4c6b5;
    height: 12px;
    margin: 7px 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.popup-messages abbr.timestamp {
    background: #3f9684 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 11px;
}

.popup-head-right .btn-group {
    display: inline-flex;
 margin: 0 8px 0 0;
 vertical-align: top !important;
}
.chat-header-button {
    background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #636364;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}
.popup-head-right .btn-group .dropdown-menu {
    border: medium none;
    min-width: 122px;
 padding: 0;
}
.popup-head-right .btn-group .dropdown-menu li a {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 3px 10px;
 color: #303030;
}

.popup-messages abbr.timestamp {
    background: #3f9684  none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 11px;
}
.popup-messages .chat-box-single-line {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a4c6b5;
    height: 12px;
    margin: 7px 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.popup-messages .direct-chat-messages {
    height: auto;
}
.popup-messages .direct-chat-text {
    background: #dfece7 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #dfece7;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #1f2121;
}

.popup-messages .direct-chat-timestamp {
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.popup-messages .direct-chat-name {
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: 600;
 margin: 0 0 0 49px !important;
 color: #fff;
 opacity: 0.9;
}
.popup-messages .direct-chat-nameTo {
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: 600;
 margin: 0 0 0 150px !important;
 color: #fff;
 opacity: 0.9;
}
.popup-messages .direct-chat-info {
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.popup-messages  .big-round {
    margin: -9px 0 0 !important;
}
.popup-messages  .direct-chat-img {
    /*border: 1px solid #fff;*/
 background: #3f9684  none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    margin: -21px 0 0;
    width: 40px;
}
.direct-chat-reply-name {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.direct-chat-img-reply-small
{
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 8px;
    width: 20px;
 background:#3f9684;
}

.popup-messages .direct-chat-msg {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.popup-messages .doted-border::after {
 background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
    border-right: 2px dotted #fff !important;
 bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    left: 17px;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 2px;
  display: inline;
   z-index: -2;
}

.popup-messages .direct-chat-msg::after {
    border-right: medium none;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    left: 17px;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 2px;
  display: inline;
   z-index: -2;
}
.direct-chat-text::after, .direct-chat-text::before {
   
    border-color: transparent #dfece7 transparent transparent;
    
}
.direct-chat-text::after, .direct-chat-text::before {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    border-color: transparent #d2d6de transparent transparent;
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: medium;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    top: 15px;
    width: 0;
}
.direct-chat-text::after {
    border-width: 5px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
.popup-messages .direct-chat-text {
    background: #dfece7 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #dfece7;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #1f2121;
}
.direct-chat-text {
    background: #d2d6de none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #d2d6de;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #444;
    margin: 5px 0 0 50px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="addClass"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Open in chat </a>
 <div class="popup-box chat-popup" id="qnimate">
    <div class="popup-head">
        <div class="popup-head-left pull-left"><img src="http://bootsnipp.com/img/avatars/bcf1c0d13e5500875fdd5a7e8ad9752ee16e7462.jpg" alt="iamgurdeeposahan"> Vendor</div>
        <div class="popup-head-right pull-right">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="chat-header-button" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i>
                </button>
                <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Email Chat</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <button data-widget="remove" id="removeClass" class="chat-header-button pull-right" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="popup-messages">




        <div class="direct-chat-messages">


            <div class="chat-box-single-line">
                <abbr class="timestamp">October 8th, 2015</abbr>
            </div>
            <!-- Message. Default to the left -->
            <div class="direct-chat-msg">
                <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                    <span class="direct-chat-name pull-left">Client</span>
                </div>
                <!-- /.direct-chat-info -->
                <img alt="message user image" src="http://bootsnipp.com/img/avatars/bcf1c0d13e5500875fdd5a7e8ad9752ee16e7462.jpg" class="direct-chat-img"><!-- /.direct-chat-img -->
                <div class="direct-chat-text">
                    Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?
                </div>
                <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                    <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">3.36 PM</span>
                </div>
                <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.direct-chat-msg -->


            <div class="chat-box-single-line">
                <abbr class="timestamp">October 9th, 2015</abbr>
            </div>
            <!-- Message. Default to the left -->
            <div class="direct-chat-msg">
                <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                    <span class="direct-chat-name">Vendor</span>
                </div>
                <!-- /.direct-chat-info -->
                <img alt="message user image" src="http://bootsnipp.com/img/avatars/bcf1c0d13e5500875fdd5a7e8ad9752ee16e7462.jpg" class="direct-chat-img"><!-- /.direct-chat-img -->
                <div class="direct-chat-text">
                    All Good Bro. How are you?
                </div>
                <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                    <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">3.36 PM</span>
                </div>
                <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.direct-chat-msg -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="popup-messages-footer">
        <textarea id="status_message" placeholder="Type a message..." rows="10" cols="40" name="message"></textarea>
        <div class="btn-footer">
            <button class="bg_none"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></i> </button>
            <button class="bg_none pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i> </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not understanding. Do you want the chat window that pops up to be on the left or the button at the top to be on the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, trying to understand the question was challenging but I think I have an example of what you are trying to achieve. It's not something you can just change with a Bootstrap class, so I created a new class called `.right-msg` and added it on the vendor's block of code.

Then, using this class you can override the left styles with the opposites for the right.

**Example:**

```js
  $(function(){
$("#addClass").click(function () {

          $('#qnimate').addClass('popup-box-on');
            });
          
            $("#removeClass").click(function () {
          $('#qnimate').removeClass('popup-box-on');
            });
  })
```

```css
   
.popup-box {
   background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
    height: 415px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 70px;
    width: 300px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.round.hollow {
    margin: 40px 0 0;
}
.round.hollow a {
    border: 2px solid #ff6701;
    border-radius: 35px;
    color: red;
    color: #ff6701;
    font-size: 23px;
    padding: 10px 21px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.round.hollow a:hover {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 35px;
    color: red;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 23px;
    padding: 10px 21px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.popup-box-on {
    display: block !important;
}
.popup-box .popup-head {
    background-color: #fff;
    clear: both;
    color: #7b7b7b;
    display: inline-table;
    font-size: 21px;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    width: 100%;
     font-family: Oswald;
}
.bg_none i {
    border: 1px solid #ff6701;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: #ff6701;
    font-size: 17px;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 33px;
}
.bg_none:hover i {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 17px;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 33px;
}
.bg_none {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: medium none;
}
.popup-box .popup-head .popup-head-right {
    margin: 11px 7px 0;
}
.popup-box .popup-messages {
}
.popup-head-left img {
    /*border: 1px solid #7b7b7b;*/
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 44px;
}
.popup-messages-footer > textarea {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b2b2b2 !important;
    height: 40px !important;
    margin: 7px;
    padding: 5px !important;
     border: medium none;
    width: 95% !important;
}
.popup-messages-footer {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.popup-messages-footer .btn-footer {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2px 5px 10px 6px;
    width: 100%;
}
.simple_round {
    background: #d1d1d1 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #4b4b4b !important;
    height: 21px;
    padding: 0 0 0 1px;
    width: 21px;
}





.popup-box .popup-messages {
    background: #3f9684 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 275px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.direct-chat-messages {
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    
}
.popup-messages .chat-box-single-line {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a4c6b5;
    height: 12px;
    margin: 7px 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.popup-messages abbr.timestamp {
    background: #3f9684 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 11px;
}

.popup-head-right .btn-group {
    display: inline-flex;
 margin: 0 8px 0 0;
 vertical-align: top !important;
}
.chat-header-button {
    background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #636364;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}
.popup-head-right .btn-group .dropdown-menu {
    border: medium none;
    min-width: 122px;
 padding: 0;
}
.popup-head-right .btn-group .dropdown-menu li a {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 3px 10px;
 color: #303030;
}

.popup-messages abbr.timestamp {
    background: #3f9684  none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 11px;
}
.popup-messages .chat-box-single-line {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a4c6b5;
    height: 12px;
    margin: 7px 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.popup-messages .direct-chat-messages {
    height: auto;
}
.popup-messages .direct-chat-text {
    background: #dfece7 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #dfece7;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #1f2121;
}

.popup-messages .direct-chat-timestamp {
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.popup-messages .direct-chat-name {
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: 600;
 margin: 0 0 0 49px !important;
 color: #fff;
 opacity: 0.9;
}
.popup-messages .direct-chat-nameTo {
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: 600;
 margin: 0 0 0 150px !important;
 color: #fff;
 opacity: 0.9;
}
.popup-messages .direct-chat-info {
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.popup-messages  .big-round {
    margin: -9px 0 0 !important;
}
.popup-messages  .direct-chat-img {
    /*border: 1px solid #fff;*/
 background: #3f9684  none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    margin: -21px 0 0;
    width: 40px;
}
.popup-messages  .right-msg .direct-chat-img {
  float: right!important;
  }

.popup-messages .right-msg .direct-chat-text {
  margin: 5px 50px 0 0;
}

.popup-messages .right-msg .direct-chat-text::before {
  border-width: 0;
}

.popup-messages .right-msg .direct-chat-text::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 100%;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #dfece7;
}

.popup-messages .right-msg .direct-chat-name {
  margin: 0 49px 0 0 !important;
  float: right;
}

.direct-chat-reply-name {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.direct-chat-img-reply-small
{
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 8px;
    width: 20px;
 background:#3f9684;
}

.popup-messages .direct-chat-msg {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.popup-messages .doted-border::after {
 background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
    border-right: 2px dotted #fff !important;
 bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    left: 17px;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 2px;
  display: inline;
   z-index: -2;
}

.popup-messages .direct-chat-msg::after {
    border-right: medium none;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    left: 17px;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 2px;
  display: inline;
   z-index: -2;
}
.direct-chat-text::after, .direct-chat-text::before {
   
    border-color: transparent #dfece7 transparent transparent;
    
}
.direct-chat-text::after, .direct-chat-text::before {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    border-color: transparent #dfece7 transparent transparent;
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: medium;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    top: 15px;
    width: 0;
}
.direct-chat-text::after {
    border-width: 5px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
.popup-messages .direct-chat-text {
    background: #dfece7 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #dfece7;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #1f2121;
}
.direct-chat-text {
    background: #d2d6de none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #d2d6de;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #444;
    margin: 5px 0 0 50px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


 <a href="#" id="addClass"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Open in chat </a>
 <div class="popup-box chat-popup" id="qnimate">
    <div class="popup-head">
        <div class="popup-head-left pull-left"><img src="http://bootsnipp.com/img/avatars/bcf1c0d13e5500875fdd5a7e8ad9752ee16e7462.jpg" alt="iamgurdeeposahan"> Vendor</div>
        <div class="popup-head-right pull-right">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="chat-header-button" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i>
                </button>
                <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Email Chat</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <button data-widget="remove" id="removeClass" class="chat-header-button pull-right" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="popup-messages">




        <div class="direct-chat-messages">


            <div class="chat-box-single-line">
                <abbr class="timestamp">October 8th, 2015</abbr>
            </div>
            <!-- Message. Default to the left -->
            <div class="direct-chat-msg">
                <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                    <span class="direct-chat-name pull-left">Client</span>
                </div>
                <!-- /.direct-chat-info -->
                <img alt="message user image" src="http://bootsnipp.com/img/avatars/bcf1c0d13e5500875fdd5a7e8ad9752ee16e7462.jpg" class="direct-chat-img"><!-- /.direct-chat-img -->
                <div class="direct-chat-text">
                    Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?
                </div>
                <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                    <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">3.36 PM</span>
                </div>
                <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.direct-chat-msg -->


            <div class="chat-box-single-line">
                <abbr class="timestamp">October 9th, 2015</abbr>
            </div>
            <!-- Message. Default to the left -->
            <div class="direct-chat-msg right-msg">
                <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                    <span class="direct-chat-name">Vendor</span>
                </div>
                <!-- /.direct-chat-info -->
                <img alt="message user image" src="http://bootsnipp.com/img/avatars/bcf1c0d13e5500875fdd5a7e8ad9752ee16e7462.jpg" class="direct-chat-img"><!-- /.direct-chat-img -->
                <div class="direct-chat-text">
                    All Good Bro. How are you?
                </div>
                <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                    <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">3.36 PM</span>
                </div>
                <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.direct-chat-msg -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="popup-messages-footer">
        <textarea id="status_message" placeholder="Type a message..." rows="10" cols="40" name="message"></textarea>
        <div class="btn-footer">
            <button class="bg_none"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></i> </button>
            <button class="bg_none pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i> </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Dom. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Give `left:70px` instead of `right` to `.popup-box`class.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#addClass").click(function() {
     $('#qnimate').addClass('popup-box-on');
  });

  $("#removeClass").click(function() {
     $('#qnimate').removeClass('popup-box-on');
  });
})
```

```css
.popup-box {
   background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
    height: 415px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 70px;
    width: 300px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.round.hollow {
    margin: 40px 0 0;
}
.round.hollow a {
    border: 2px solid #ff6701;
    border-radius: 35px;
    color: red;
    color: #ff6701;
    font-size: 23px;
    padding: 10px 21px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.round.hollow a:hover {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 35px;
    color: red;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 23px;
    padding: 10px 21px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.popup-box-on {
    display: block !important;
}
.popup-box .popup-head {
    background-color: #fff;
    clear: both;
    color: #7b7b7b;
    display: inline-table;
    font-size: 21px;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    width: 100%;
     font-family: Oswald;
}
.bg_none i {
    border: 1px solid #ff6701;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: #ff6701;
    font-size: 17px;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 33px;
}
.bg_none:hover i {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 17px;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 33px;
}
.bg_none {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: medium none;
}
.popup-box .popup-head .popup-head-right {
    margin: 11px 7px 0;
}
.popup-box .popup-messages {
}
.popup-head-left img {
    /*border: 1px solid #7b7b7b;*/
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 44px;
}
.popup-messages-footer > textarea {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b2b2b2 !important;
    height: 40px !important;
    margin: 7px;
    padding: 5px !important;
     border: medium none;
    width: 95% !important;
}
.popup-messages-footer {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.popup-messages-footer .btn-footer {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2px 5px 10px 6px;
    width: 100%;
}
.simple_round {
    background: #d1d1d1 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #4b4b4b !important;
    height: 21px;
    padding: 0 0 0 1px;
    width: 21px;
}





.popup-box .popup-messages {
    background: #3f9684 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 275px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.direct-chat-messages {
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    
}
.popup-messages .chat-box-single-line {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a4c6b5;
    height: 12px;
    margin: 7px 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.popup-messages abbr.timestamp {
    background: #3f9684 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 11px;
}

.popup-head-right .btn-group {
    display: inline-flex;
 margin: 0 8px 0 0;
 vertical-align: top !important;
}
.chat-header-button {
    background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #636364;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}
.popup-head-right .btn-group .dropdown-menu {
    border: medium none;
    min-width: 122px;
 padding: 0;
}
.popup-head-right .btn-group .dropdown-menu li a {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 3px 10px;
 color: #303030;
}

.popup-messages abbr.timestamp {
    background: #3f9684  none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 11px;
}
.popup-messages .chat-box-single-line {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a4c6b5;
    height: 12px;
    margin: 7px 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.popup-messages .direct-chat-messages {
    height: auto;
}
.popup-messages .direct-chat-text {
    background: #dfece7 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #dfece7;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #1f2121;
}

.popup-messages .direct-chat-timestamp {
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.popup-messages .direct-chat-name {
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: 600;
 margin: 0 0 0 49px !important;
 color: #fff;
 opacity: 0.9;
}
.popup-messages .direct-chat-nameTo {
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: 600;
 margin: 0 0 0 150px !important;
 color: #fff;
 opacity: 0.9;
}
.popup-messages .direct-chat-info {
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.popup-messages  .big-round {
    margin: -9px 0 0 !important;
}
.popup-messages  .direct-chat-img {
    /*border: 1px solid #fff;*/
 background: #3f9684  none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    margin: -21px 0 0;
    width: 40px;
}
.direct-chat-reply-name {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.direct-chat-img-reply-small
{
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 8px;
    width: 20px;
 background:#3f9684;
}

.popup-messages .direct-chat-msg {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.popup-messages .doted-border::after {
 background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
    border-right: 2px dotted #fff !important;
 bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    left: 17px;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 2px;
  display: inline;
   z-index: -2;
}

.popup-messages .direct-chat-msg::after {
    border-right: medium none;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    left: 17px;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 2px;
  display: inline;
   z-index: -2;
}
.direct-chat-text::after, .direct-chat-text::before {
   
    border-color: transparent #dfece7 transparent transparent;
    
}
.direct-chat-text::after, .direct-chat-text::before {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    border-color: transparent #d2d6de transparent transparent;
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: medium;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    top: 15px;
    width: 0;
}
.direct-chat-text::after {
    border-width: 5px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
.popup-messages .direct-chat-text {
    background: #dfece7 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #dfece7;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #1f2121;
}
.direct-chat-text {
    background: #d2d6de none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #d2d6de;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #444;
    margin: 5px 0 0 50px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a href="#" id="addClass"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Open in chat </a>
<div class="popup-box chat-popup" id="qnimate">
  <div class="popup-head">
    <div class="popup-head-left pull-left"><img src="http://bootsnipp.com/img/avatars/bcf1c0d13e5500875fdd5a7e8ad9752ee16e7462.jpg" alt="iamgurdeeposahan"> Vendor</div>
    <div class="popup-head-right pull-right">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="chat-header-button" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i>
        </button>
        <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
          <li><a href="#">Email Chat</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <button data-widget="remove" id="removeClass" class="chat-header-button pull-right" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="popup-messages">
    <div class="direct-chat-messages">
      <div class="chat-box-single-line">
        <abbr class="timestamp">October 8th, 2015</abbr>
      </div>
      <!-- Message. Default to the left -->
      <div class="direct-chat-msg">
        <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
          <span class="direct-chat-name pull-left">Client</span>
        </div>
        <!-- /.direct-chat-info -->
        <img alt="message user image" src="http://bootsnipp.com/img/avatars/bcf1c0d13e5500875fdd5a7e8ad9752ee16e7462.jpg" class="direct-chat-img">
        <!-- /.direct-chat-img -->
        <div class="direct-chat-text">
          Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?Hey bro, how’s everything going ?
        </div>
        <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
          <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">3.36 PM</span>
        </div>
        <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.direct-chat-msg -->
      <div class="chat-box-single-line">
        <abbr class="timestamp">October 9th, 2015</abbr>
      </div>
      <!-- Message. Default to the left -->
      <div class="direct-chat-msg">
        <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
          <span class="direct-chat-name">Vendor</span>
        </div>
        <!-- /.direct-chat-info -->
        <img alt="message user image" src="http://bootsnipp.com/img/avatars/bcf1c0d13e5500875fdd5a7e8ad9752ee16e7462.jpg" class="direct-chat-img">
        <!-- /.direct-chat-img -->
        <div class="direct-chat-text">
          All Good Bro. How are you?
        </div>
        <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
          <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">3.36 PM</span>
        </div>
        <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.direct-chat-msg -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="popup-messages-footer">
    <textarea id="status_message" placeholder="Type a message..." rows="10" cols="40" name="message"></textarea>
    <div class="btn-footer">
      <button class="bg_none"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></i> </button>
      <button class="bg_none pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i> </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think I was not very clear. I have edited my question.